# While constructing the default constructor can not handle exception : type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor

Tags: java, exception

The code works fine until I try to make the code into a constructable class. When I attempt to construct an object from it I get the error

> "Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

This is when having to throw exceptions to `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
FileReader textFilethree = new FileReader (xFile);
BufferedReader bufferedTextthree = new BufferedReader (textFilethree) ;
String lineThree = bufferedTextthree.readLine();
```

The xFile is gotten from the construction. Note that within this construction exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 6):

Default constructor implicitly invokes super constructor which is assumed to be throwing some exception which you need to handle in sub class's constructor . for detailed answer post the code

```
class Base{

  public Base() throw SomeException{
    //some code
  }

}

class Child extends Base{
  public Child(){
   //here it implicitly invokes `Base()`, So handle it here
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add relevant construtor's

Comment: It just has the parameter for FileReader as a parameter of the constructor with exceptions thrown.

Comment: so you need to catch or throw it in sub class's constructor

Comment: Yea I did throw it, but then I got the error message in my IDE when I tried to construct.

Comment: again you need to handle it while constructing. it propogates

Comment: Wait I don't understand how your example applies, I don't have any subclasses.

Sorry for not understanding

Comment: @JigarJoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1687/discussion-between-user853056-and-jigar-joshi)

Answer (score 3):

Base class super.constructor is implicitly invoked by the extending class constructor:

```
class Base
{
  public Base () throws Exception
  {
    throw <>;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
  public Derived ()
  {
  }
}
```

Now, one need to handle the exception inside `Derived()` or make the constructor as,

```
public Derived() throws Exception
{
}
```

Whatever method you `new` up the object of `Derived`, either you enclose it in `try-catch` or make that method throwing `Exception` as above.
[Note: this is pseudo code]

Comment: I'm thinking of erring on forgetting about the ide error, I ran it and it was fine.

Will I run into problems later if I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose your call to the Constructor in a Try-Catch.

Answer (score 0):

Any subclass which extends a super class whose default constructor handles some exception, a subclass must have a default constructor which implements the exception

class Super{
    public Super() throws Exception {}}

class Sub extends Super{public Sub()throws Exception{//}}

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this

```
class example{
    public void fileReader(String path) throws Exception{
         //some code that throws Exception
    }
 }
```

Make sure to use that same sintaxis on the method you are trying to make the object

```
class implementation{
     public void someMethod() throws Exception{
          example object = new example();
          example.filereader("C:\\....");
      }
  }
```

happened to me while using apache poi