# Java error: Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, file-io, constructor, compiler-errors

I'm trying to read input from a file to be taken into a Java applet to be displayed as a Pac-man level, but I need to use something similar to getLine()... So I searched for something similar, and this is the code I found:

```
File inFile = new File("textfile.txt");
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);//ERROR
// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

The line I marked "ERROR" gives me an error that says "Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor."

I've searched for this error message, but everything I find seems to be unrelated to my situation.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, we don't know the context of what you have posted above.

Comment: See this related post: [While constructing the default constructor can not handle exception : type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772709/while-constructing-the-default-constructor-can-not-handle-exception-type-excep).

Comment: You didn't even quote the error message accurately. It does tell you exactly what the problem is, but not if you don't read what's actually there.

Answer (score 9):

Either declare a explicit constructor at your subclass that throws `FileNotFoundException`:

```
public MySubClass() throws FileNotFoundException {
}
```

Or surround the code in your base class with a `try-catch` block instead of throwing a `FileNotFoundException` exception:

```
public MyBaseClass()  {
    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    try {
        File inFile = new File("textfile.txt");
        fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Do something with the stream
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            // If you don't need the stream open after the constructor
            // else, remove that block but don't forget to close the 
            // stream after you are done with it
            fstream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }  
}
```

Unrelated, but since you are coding a Java applet, remember that you will need to [sign it](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) in order to perform IO operations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your code with try and catch as follows:

```
try {
    File inFile = new File("textfile.txt");
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);//ERROR
} catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
    fe.printStackTrace();
}
// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: Adel, `fstream` is not visible to the `DataInputStream` constructor if you write your code like this. You need to refactor your code and have a null referenced `fstream` outside of the try block like I did in my example. Also, since you are not surrounding the entire block with a try / catch statement, it is not a bad idea to check for `fstream != null` before declaring the `in` and `br` variables.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I didn't present a complete solution, I just gave you a clue, the try and catch should envelop all lines which can produce the mentioned error. Sadly, I didn't check which lines do that. It is up to you to use it at your convenience :)

Answer (score 0):

This is guesswork as we don't have the complete code.

From the Javadoc:

```
public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
```

It means that when you do a new `FileInputStream()` like you do, it can come back with a `FileNotFoundException`. This is a checked exception, that you need to either rethrow (i.e. add 'throws FileNotFoundException' in the method where you do the new) or catch (see other try/catch responses).