# Default constructor cannot handle exception type SocketException thrown by implicit super constructor

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an android app that will be able to switch between 3G and 4G manually by making a call and sending out a package simultaneously. When I end the call, the package will continue to send keeping the phone in 3G, but then when I push a button, it terminates the package.

I'm fine on most of the code, but I got the program to send the package from someone else and I'm a bit confused on how I get it running, specifically this one error I'm getting when I declare the field *socket*. I get an error message saying "Default constructor cannot handle exception type SocketException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor."

Here's my class file for the package:

```
package com.example.derpphone;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class timer extends TimerTask {


    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    @Override
    public void run() {     
                if (socket != null) {
                                   byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
                    SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("131.179.176.74",
                            9998);
                    try {
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes,
                                bytes.length, serverAddress);
                        socket.send(packet);                    

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772709/while-constructing-the-default-constructor-can-not-handle-exception-type-excep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
DatagramSocket socket; 

public timer() throws Exception {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
```

When you write:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

without a default constructor, it is equivalent to:

```
DatagramSocket socket;

public timer() {  
    super();
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
```

As DatagramSocket constructor throws an exception, this needs to be caught or declared.

Answer (score 1):

it means that

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

could throw an `SocketException`, because default constructor [`DatagramSocket()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket%28%29) declares so,  It must be handled or re-throw back, and there is no way to handle it like this so you would nee a constructor around it

change it to

```
DatagramSocket socket;

public timer throws SocketException { 
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
```