# Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. of Fileinputstream

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having two java files :
1) Readfiledata.java

```
public class ReadFileData {
protected Properties prop = new Properties();
public ReadFileData() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream  inputStream= new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Resources\\config.properties");   
    prop.load(inputStream);
}
```

}

2) Login.java

```
ReadFileData data= new ReadFileData();
```

in this file on creating a object of readfiledata , I am seeing the error.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [While constructing the default constructor can not handle exception : type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772709/while-constructing-the-default-constructor-can-not-handle-exception-type-excep)

Answer (score 0):

where ever you are calling this method, put this in try and catch block.
try{ReadFileData data= new ReadFileData();}catch(IOException exception){            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());}