# Java: Cannot initialize InetAddress

Tags: java, inetaddress

I can't seem to be able to initialize InetAddress object for some reason, I looked at the documentation and it is exactly as how I use it.

```
 InetAddress firstMachineAddress = InetAddress.getByName("129.26.70.95");
 InetAddress secondMachineAddress = InetAddress.getByName("129.26.70.108");
```

And Eclipse says:

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnknownHostException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

What the heck is wrong?

Comment: If you have the *ip address* of the host you shoud use *getByAddress()* not *getByName()*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While constructing the default constructor can not handle exception : type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772709/while-constructing-the-default-constructor-can-not-handle-exception-type-excep)

Comment: @MarioSantini That gives the same error.

Comment: @xehpuk The question has no valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be in a class's constructor which is extended by another class, like so:

```
import java.net.*;

class SuperclassWithUnknownHostException {
    public SuperclassWithUnknownHostException() throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress firstMachineAddress = InetAddress.getByName("129.26.70.95");
        InetAddress secondMachineAddress = InetAddress.getByName("129.26.70.108");
    }
}

class SubclassCannotHandleException extends SuperclassWithUnknownHostException {

}
```

You need to add a default constructor to the subclass which throws the exception:

```
class SubclassCannotHandleException extends SuperclassWithUnknownHostException {
    public SubclassCannotHandleException() throws UnknownHostException {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the `UnknownHostException` thrown by the method you call?

```java
InetAddress firstMachineAddress;
try {
    firstMachineAddress = InetAddress.getByName("129.26.70.95");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // print exception, throw error,
    // try something else etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inetAddress object throws an exception for one, so you will need to wrap a try-catch around it or have your method throw an exception as well.  Also I believe you are getting the error because there is an exception coming back that you are not handling.  The getByName() method uses the a string parameter of the name of the webaddress like www.google.com or www.amazon.com and so forth.

```
try{
        InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"); 
        System.out.println(Address);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This displays www.google.com/64.233.177.147